# AddMauiBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools don't exist

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor, maui

In this microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/blazorwebview) is recommended to use `builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();` but when i use it my VS gives an error saying that this directive doesn't exist... I'm using `builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();` for now.

Does anyone know why I can't use this?

I tried to use this as indicated in the documentation, I looked for some solutions on the internet, but nothing very concrete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create a .NET MAUI Blazor app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/maui) directly. It's the equivalent of adding BlazorWebView to an existing app, automating those [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/blazorwebview?view=net-maui-7.0#add-a-blazorwebview-to-an-existing-app). For example it contains the following code:

```cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
#if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
#endif
        // Register any app services on the IServiceCollection object
        // e.g. builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

You can try it. It will not report an error like this: "directive doesn't exist..."

Comment: my Error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1061)

Comment: I mean you can try the above method to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui" package installed.

Comment: I have this package :/